# Clipboard text converted to Chinese like characters inside C++

Tags: string, visual-c++, unicode, utf, wstring

I have a code to take the clipboard value to perform some function in Archicad-API which works with C++. But when I debug the code in Visual Studio, I can see that the clipboard value is converted to a Chinese like String, it is not in English anymore, how can I fix this?
This is how it looks like.
abcdefgh -> "扡摣晥"

Comment: What you describe is typically referred to as ["Mojibake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). It can happen when you *misinterpret* data that is encoded in one format as if it were a different format. In this case, you are misinterpreting an 8bit ANSI string as if it were a 16bit Unicode string. The 8bit string `"abcdefgh"` and the 16bit string `"扡摣晥"` are comprised of the same 8bit bytes. Don't mix up character encodings.

Comment: The type of the variable is probably `wchar_t *` but it should be `char *` instead.